# SubConsulta MySql

Tags: sql-select

Tenho uma tabela de funcionários que tem apenas três colunas, `NOME`, `CARGO` e `SALARIO`, quero montar um consulta que me traga toda esta tabela e nela contenha o maior valor de salário para o cargo. Totalizando 4 Colunas (`NOME`, `CARGO`, `SALARIO` e `MAIOR_SALARIO_P_CARGO`. Isto é para verificar a variação.

Comment: Dê mais informações. Qual a tabela onde está o quarto campo. Qual a relação entre elas?

Comment: Dica: para editar esta pergunta, use o link de [edit] acima.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    T1.NOME,
    T1.CARGO,
    T1.SALARIO_ATUAL,
    (
        SELECT MAX(SALARIO_ATUAL)
        FROM TABELA T2
        WHERE T2.CARGO = T1.CARGO
    ) AS MAIOR_SALARIO_PARA_CARGO
FROM TABELA T1
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Respostas:

***SubQuery***

```
SELECT a.nome, a.cargo, a.salario, (select max(salario) from tbsalarios b where b.cargo = a.cargo) maiorsalario FROM tbsalarios a
```

---

***JOIN***

```
SELECT a.nome, 
       a.cargo, 
       a.salario, 
       b.maior 
FROM tbsalarios a 
LEFT JOIN 
      (select max(salario) maior, cargo from tbsalarios group by cargo) as b on b.cargo = a.cargo
```